# Cordova Phonegap Barcode plugin won't launch from my Intel XDK app

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, intel-xdk

I have been building small app with Intel XDK. I try to open Phonegap Barcode scanner but when launch button is clicked nothing happens. My goal is to scan a QR code and open inAppBrowser link containing result data. I have both Device (cordova-plugin-device) and Barcode Scanner (phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner) plugins installed with permissions for camera and flash.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">           

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", scanNow, false);

     function scanNow() {

cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
  function (result) {
    //  alert("We got a barcode\n" +
     //      "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
     //       "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
     //       "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);

         window.open("http://www.example.com?qr=" + result.text, '_system', 'location=no');


  }, 
  function (error) {
      alert("Error: " + error); 
  });}

</script>
```

And this is the launch button:

```
<a role='button' onclick="scanNow();">Scan</a>
```

EDIT: I solved the problem by adding this link to a dummy script to my index page head.

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call your `scanNow()` function on the `deviceready` event, you just need to insure that calls to it do not happen until *after* the `deviceready` event has fired. Since you're debugging, I would change that line to something like...

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", alertDeviceReady, false);
```

...and add an `alertDeviceReady()` that gives you an alert or console message. Usually it takes a second or two, but can take longer on slow devices or if you've got some plugins that require a long init time.

This is going to be a security problem...

```
window.open("http://www.example.com?qr=" + result.text, '_system', 'location=no');
```

...because you should not open the webview to another page (you're navigating away from the built-in webview that your app is running inside of, you're not associated with a website).

You can use `inAppBrowser` to open an alternate view on top of the webview, but I advise that you use the explictly named `inAppBrowser` APIs and do not assume that it has been aliased to use `window.open()` -- because they have deprecated that usage and, I believe, it is not aliased in the default installation anymore. That is, try using...

```
cordova.inAppBrowser.open()
```

...instead.

See the [docs here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) which will also include details regarding the current release for that plugin (which may only work with CLI 5+ builds) and contains a link to the github repo for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and pointing out the security problem with the link. I solved the main problem by adding link to this dummy file <script src="cordova.js"></script> within the head of my index page.

Comment: Definitely need that to make any Cordova plugins work, that is a magic script that is created and added to your app at build time. It initializes the Cordova framework and calls the init functions for all the Cordova plugins you've included with your app. That is the code that generates the {{deviceready}} event, and why it is important to wait for the {{deviceready}} event to be issued before you call any Cordova plugin APIs.